# How can I get the last matched line for each job ( awk )

Tags: awk

I am trying to extract the last line of each job(eg. 2 or 6 / first digit in the line) and the line should include the text 'LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT'.
With the code below, I can just get the last line of total strings as follows. However, I need to print the last line of each job.

Can you advise me on this matter?

@ code

```
awk  '/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/ {a=$0} END{print a}'  tempResult
```

@ Result

```
6/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/99999
```

@ Input file ( tempResult )

```
2/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/99999
2/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/99999
2/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/99999
2/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/99999
2/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/99999
2/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/99999
2/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/99999
2/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/100000
2/Loader.log/LOADER_COMPLETED
6/Loader.log/LOADER_START
6/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/0
6/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/0
6/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/0
6/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/95882
6/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/99999
6/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/99999
```

@ Expected Result

```
2/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/100000
6/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/99999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = "/" } $0 ~ /LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/{ a[$1] = $0 }END{ for (i in a) print a[i] } file
```

Output:

```
6/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/99999
2/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/100000
```

Comment: `$0 ~ ` is implied when missing.

Answer (score 1):

if the `Loader.log` part can be variable too, this line may help:

```
 awk '/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/{t=$0;sub(/\/[^/]*$/,"",t);a[t]=$0} 
      END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' file
```

Note the order of lines in output may not preserved.

Comment: why don't you trust the field delimiter?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. There are so many great people in the world.

Comment: @karakfa I thought each "field" could be different, so if I take `$x`, I have to compare them, or combine them together. and, with `sub(...)` I don't have to care `OFS`...

Comment: if you don't overwrite a field, the line doesn't need to be reconstructed and  `OFS` is not needed.  But, I guess some `awk`s might...

Answer (score 1):

with `tac/tac` help you can find the first instances and order is preserved

```
tac file | 
awk -F'/' '/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/ && !a[$1]++' | 
tac

2/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/100000
6/Loader.log/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/99999
```

Answer (score 1):

try: If your Input_file is of same like sample shown and ids(first fields) are in order then following may help you too.

```
awk -F"/" '/LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT/{VAL=$0;} VAR != $1 && VAR{print VAL} {VAR=$1} END{print VAL}'  Input_file
```

Making field separator as / then looking for string LOADER_PROCESSED_COUNT, if yes then creating a variable named VAL and saving line's value in it. Then checking a condition where VAR is not equal to $1 and VAR is NOT NULL then printing the variable named VAL. Assigning variable VAL to $1 at the end of each line read, so that we could compare it next time. Then in END section block printing the value of VAL too.